# How to combine vue-multiselect with vue-treeSelect?

Tags: vue.js, nested, vue-multiselect

I'm working with Vue.js and I need a "smart" search bar.
I've ended up with vue-multiselect, but I need to have nested menus in the dropdown.
Apparently, there's something called treeSelect that can help me with that, but I don't know how to combine them together.
The code is pretty basic.

```
<template>
<div>
      <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options"  placeholder="Pick a value" style="width:600px;"></multiselect>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">


import { Multiselect } from 'vue-multiselect'

@Component({
    components: {
    Multiselect,
  },
})
export default class Income extends Vue {
  public Multiselect= Multiselect;
  data () {
    return {
      value: '',
      options: ['first','second','third','forth','fifth']
    }
  }

}
```

I need the "search-select" bar to be able of searching, nesting and showing disabled options.
I would really need some help, and why not, some advice and guidance :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this.https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGqXGa

`for more information visit` - https://vue-treeselect.js.org/#disable-item-selection

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I'm trying to use treeselect, but I'm also using typescript.
So, after some research, I found that these two are not compatible.
I have to start looking for an alternative for TreeSelect; a dropdown that supports nesting